# Doing DISTINCT on a subject in WHERE clause SPARQL query

Tags: sparql, rdf

My data schema is as:
`<user> <:bought> <book>`

I am trying to write a recommendation query for suggesting new books to a user. For eg. if a user `u_a` has bought books `b_1` and `b_2`. I find all the users (other than `u_a`) who bought `b_1` and `b_2`, and those other users bought other books (other than `b_1` and `b_2`).

```
SELECT ?otherbooks (COUNT(*) AS ?t)
FROM <https://book_store1>
WHERE {
    <https://book_store1/userId/1495865> <https://book_store1/bought> ?booksbought .
    FILTER (?user != <https://book_store1/userId/1495865>)
    ?user <https://book_store1/bought> ?booksbought .
    FILTER (?otherbooks != ?booksbought)
    ?user <https://book_store1/bought> ?otherbooks .
    }
GROUP BY ?otherbooks
ORDER BY DESC (?t)
LIMIT 10
```

In the 3rd line in `WHERE` clause i.e. `?user <https://book_store1/bought> ?booksbought .`, I want to do `DISTINCT` users i.e. `u_b` and `u_c` might have bought both `b_1` and `b_2`. So, I want to pass single value as `u_b` and `u_c` each as `?user` in subsequent WHERE clause

Comment: `SELECT ?otherbooks (COUNT(DISTINCT ?user) AS ?t)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapt your count to look at unique users, like this:

```
SELECT ?otherbooks (COUNT(DISTINCT ?user) AS ?t)
```